# Same code gives different result in Codepen and dev tools console

Tags: javascript

```
function func(n1) { 
  const foo = n2 => func(n1 + n2)
  foo.toString = () => n1
  return foo;
}

const fo = func(3)
console.log(fo(10))
```

This is my solution for a Codewars kata. Codewars wanted me to return a number and it actually returns a number in Codewars and Codepen also. But when I paste it to the browser console I get the `foo` function, not a number.

Why does this happen? What's the difference between Copeden console and browser console? And how do I return a number in  browser console?

Comment: Erm...your function always returns a function. So, that's what you'll always get out of it. It might be stringified for the console but that's implementation dependent.

Comment: but doesn't `foo.toString = () => n1` work as a return in case we expect a string? And Codepen console gives me number 13 as a result. So the function not always return another function

Comment: "*but doesn't foo.toString = () => n1 work as a return in case we expect a string?*" yes, *if it's converted to a string*. There is no guarantee, nor spec that says that logging to the console should do that. How the console handles objects (which includes functions) is implementation dependent. It might call `toString` on them, it might not. It might not even convert them to a string at all. The browser console doesn't - just prints a live reference to the object.

Comment: thank you!! Post this a an answer and I'mm mark it as a solution